# How do i adjust zoom of navigation bar HTML

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

When I zoom in my page the Navigation Bar messes up and some options go below others.

CSS

```
.mySlides {display:none;}

.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 17px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

body {margin:0;}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00cc66;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

HTML

```
    <ul>
  <li><a  href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can i prevent this from happening in this and other occasions with more elements like images as well?
Do I need to include some libraries like Bootstrap or do I simply need to change my CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `ul` width to 100% and `li` width to 25% will make it adjust to cover screen.

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: if i zoom the image gets overlapped with the navbar. How can i prevent this from happening as well?